# Informal way of saying the computer mouse is not functioning well

Tags: vocabulary, phrasal-verbs

My son wants to watch the children's TV show, Peg + Cat on his computer. He scrolled the mouse down to the show's folder, but when he double clicks on the folder, it does not open; a pop up menu displays instead.
I wanted to tell him that the mouse is not functioning well because the right button was stuck.

1. Do you informally say the mouse is busted/broken? If not, what do you say? Bear in mind the mouse still scrolls and sometimes with a few clicks 'it gets on'.
2. By the way, is using 'it gets on' to mean 'it works' correct? If not what phrasal verb would you use instead?

Comment: as a Computer Programmer I would define a situation like "right mouse button stuck" as simply "mouse stuck", instead of saying "it's broken". Which also means it will keep working.

Comment: Back in the day when mice had mechanical balls that would occasionally get dirty and not function correctly, 'Bollocksed' was considered informally appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If an item does not work fully as expected, it is perfectly fine to call it *broken* (normal) or *busted* (informal) - you can distinguish with something fully non-functional by calling those items *completely broken* (normal) / *totally busted* (informal).

In answer to your second question - no. If the object is functional, you cannot say "*it gets on*". You can say "*it turns on*" if you want to, but it would be more normal to just say "*it works*" or "*it's working normally*".

Answer (score 3):

Here are two words/expressions you could use:

> The mouse is ***flaky***.

NOAD lists one meaning of *flaky* as:

> **flaky** (*adj.*) `informal` (of a device or software) prone to break down; unreliable.

The other expression is:

> We'll have to get a new mouse soon. The mouse here is ***on the fritz***.

[Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/fritz) defines this expression to mean:

> **on the fritz** `US informal` broken or not working: *The fridge is on the fritz*.

[Another dictionary](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/fritz) says:

> A condition in which something does not work properly: *Our television is on the fritz*

I often hear "on the fritz" when someone is referring to electronic systems and devices in particular – that is, things such as computer monitors, air conditioners, microwave ovens, and the like. You can see several published examples on [this page](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22on%20the%20fritz%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1980,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en#lr=lang_en&q=%22on+the+fritz%22&start=60&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1980,cd_max:2000,lr%3alang_1en).

Comment: I never heard *on the fritz* before, but [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+the+blink%2Con+the+fritz&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20the%20blink%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20fritz%3B%2Cc0) suggests it's primarily an Americanism. For all that, in the written form at least, *on the **blink*** seems to be more common on both sides of the Atlantic. It's certainly what I'd use.

Comment: @Fumble - Almost every source I checked listed as an Americanism. I've heard of "on the blink," but I think "on the fritz" would be a bit more common over here. Thanks for offering up an alternative that works on either side of the ocean.

Comment: [COCA](http://corpus2.byu.edu/coca/) appears to confirm that "on the fritz" is slightly more common over here.  It has 66 results, compared to 45 results for "on the blink".

Answer (score 2):

In this case where a computer mouse is not working fully, you can say that it is *not working properly*. The word *busted* can be used informally but, it is not in common use everywhere. It is probably part of American English. The word *broken* can also be used but, would require clarification to make clear whether something is partly or completley broken.

Regarding the second question, I agree with Matt's answer.

Comment: I agree with @Tristan if something is partially broken you should make a clarification.

Answer (score 1):

A very common way to say this is simply "there is something wrong with the mouse".

This wording doesn't imply any diagnosis of the mouse being broken.